# Why a bignumber is shown incomplete in ECLiPSe Prolog?

Tags: logging, prolog, bignum, eclipse-clp

I use the latest version of ECLiPSe Prolog 64-bit for Windows, then I compile the code:

```
:- op(200, yf, !).
!(N, F) :- fac(N, 1, F).
fac(0, F0, F) :- !, F=F0.
fac(N, F0, F) :- N1 is N-1, F1 is F0*N, fac(N1, F1, F).
```

Query entered:

```
?- X is 100000 !.
X = 28242294079603478742934215200555696886678...
Yes (8.17s cpu)
```

**First question:** Why shows only 1999 digits and no the 456574 complete digits in TkEclipse?

**Second question:** Offers the possibility to log the interaction with the user on a file ECLiPSe Prolog as protocol(+File) of SWI-Prolog?

I'm sorry for doing two questions. I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Seems to be Tk-specific. The < 500k characters are printed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Works with DosEclipse from Version 7.0 #36 (x86_64_nt):

[image]

**Edit 31.01.2018:** Time shown the same when no output is generated.

Answer (score 0):

ECLiPSe does print the complete result to a stream called `answer_output`, but the text is later truncated by the graphical user interface.

The easiest way to get the result into a file is to write it there explicitly, e.g.

```
?- open(myresult,write,S), X is 100000!, writeln(S,'X'=X), close(S).
```